# Stop warning from mysql terminal

Tags: mysql, linux, shell, warnings

when i use following command in my shellscript to use the mysql,

```
mysql -uUserName -pPassWord DBName
```

i get the following warning

```
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
```

my shellscript is running this command in loop to insert some data in my table, so it is giving warning continuosly on screen, that makes the output totally clumsy, so what should i do to stop printing this warning from mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your MySQL client/server version is a 5.6.x a way to avoid the WARNING message are using the **[mysql_config_editor](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-config-editor.html)** tools:

`mysql_config_editor set --login-path=local --host=localhost --user=UserName --password`

Then you can use in your shell script:

`mysql --login-path=local DBName`

instead of:

`mysql -uUserName -pPassWord DBName`

Answer (score 2):

You can put your `mysql` connection info in `~/.my.cnf`, like this:

```
[client]
database=dbsite
user=dbuser
password=dbpass
host=dbhost
```

Then you can call `mysql` without any parameters, it will take username, password, and all other details from `~/.my.cnf`.

**However, use strict permissions for this file:**

```
chmod 0600 ~/.my.cnf
```

If you don't want to pollute your `~/.my.cnf` file, you can create a file somewhere else, for example `/path/to/my.cnf.dbname`, and call `mysql` like this:

```
mysql --defaults-file=/path/to/my.cnf.dbname
```

Once again, make sure to set strict permissions for this file:

```
chmod 0600 /path/to/my.cnf.dbname
```

**UPDATE**

A common pitfall is to set `host` incorrectly. This setting must match the setting in the `mysql.user` table of your user. You can confirm your user account by running this query as the database admin:

```
select Host, User from mysql.user;
```

Alternatively, you can find the hostnames used in the server's configuration files, for example:

```
grep -r host /etc/mysql
```

However, the right path depends on your system. (This is from a standard Debian install.)

Comment: does ./.my.cnf file already exists in root directory or we have to create new one,

Comment: is it necessary to put this file in root directory or can place it at anywhere?

Comment: it is giving me error as:- ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'dbuser'@'localhost'(using password=YES)

Comment: ya i have done samething, i have just posted here dbuser for security

Comment: is it needed to replace [client](1st line) with anything

Comment: you can find the file under /etc/

you use text editor or use vi /etc/my.cnf

Comment: @MDThakkar See my update with more tips for finding the right `host` setting.

Comment: i have confirmed my user account, but it still throwing the same Warning, i am doing the same thing on my friend's computer, it is not giving me any error, i don't know what hell is with my pc..

Answer (score -1):

```
mysql -u <UserName> -p <PassWord> then press enter.

Note: if a password set then only provide the password otherwise leave it blank.

And then run a command "mysql> use <databasename>;
```

Comment: i am doing the same thing but it is giving me warning, (syntax provided by you is wrong- remove space between -p and password else it take password as name of database)